# Creating a [time,lon,lat] dimension from a multidimensional netcdf

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf, python-xarray

I have this satellite altimetry data (points, not gridded) from Jason that has unusual dimensions: time and meas_index. I would like to have a [time, lon, lat] dimension without affecting the dataset. Currently, the lat and lon are coordinates and I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62459394/how-to-convert-netcdfs-with-unusual-dimensions-to-a-standard-netcdf-ltime-lat) but we have different datasets.

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

all_lat = xr.open_dataset('dataset.nc')
```

```
xarray.Dataset
Dimensions: time: 3031 meas_ind: 20
Coordinates:
**time** (time) datetime64[ns] 2002-01-23T02:26:13.761423824 .....
**meas_ind** (meas_ind) int8 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 14 15 16 17 18 19
lat (time) float64 ...
lon (time) float64 ...
lon_20hz (time, meas_ind) float64 ...
lat_20hz (time, meas_ind) float64 ...
Data variables: (141)
Attributes: (25)
```

In addition, I only need the ssha variable, which is indexed to time while the lat and lon are coordinates.

```
xarray.DataArray'ssha' time: 3031
array([ 0.011, -0.019,  0.026, ...,    nan,    nan,    nan], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
time (time) datetime64[ns] 2002-01-23T02:26:13.761423824 .....
lat (time) float64 -66.15 -66.15 ... 66.15 66.15
lon (time) float64 34.11 34.24 34.37 ... 199.0 199.2
```

I uploaded the dataset here: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1paRUF9_hDS0dhX5qtnTL8r4pA8YgoID7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: your data can't be reindexed to (lat, lon, time). xarray dimensions must orthogonal. If the latitudes and longitudes in your data are the precise locations corresponding to each time step, then expanding the data to lat, lon, time would create a (3031, 3031, 3031) array, with only one non-null value for each time step.

Comment: Hello @MichaelDelgado, you are right thank you! I did resolve this as posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72088117/valueerror-resulting-object-does-not-have-monotonic-global-indexes-along-dimens but i do have another problem. It would help a lot if you can also check that out. Thank you so much!